# Custom error is not rendered as hal in Spring Boot 1.3 and Spring hateoas 0.19

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-hateoas, hal

Initially I used Spring Boot 1.2 and Spring hateoas in my project, and I need to customize error message. So I created our class instead of the native VndErrors and VndError.

I created a class extends VndErrors.VndError.

```
public class MyError extends VndErrors.VndError{
  //add some my custom fields
}
```

And antoher class to wrap the MyError.

```
public class ErrorDetails{
    int total;

    @JsonProperty("_embedded")
    Map<String, List<MyError>> errors;

   public ErrorDetails(List<MyError> err){
      this.total=err.size();
      errors.put("errors", err); 
   }
}
```

All exception are hanleded in a `@ContrllerAdvice` class. I used a custom `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` to configure `ObjectMapper` in our project.

**When I used Spring 1.2, it was rendered as expected**. As following.

```
{ 
  "total": 1,
  "_embedded":{
     "errors":[
       {
        //feilds,
        _links:{
         "self":""
         }
       }
     ]    
  }
}
```

But when **upgraded to Spring Boot 1.3**, it does not work as excepted.

The **_links** rendered as **links**, and the content type is **application/json** in the debug info.

**Stage 1:**

I am trying to create a simple pojo with a `List` of `Link`, it does not work.

```
public class ErrorDetails{}//pojo includes fields
public class MyError{
  //add some my custom fields
  @JsonUnwrapped
  ErrorDetails content;

  List<link> links;
}

public class ErrorResources{
    int total;

    @JsonProperty("_embedded")
    Map<String, List<MyError>> errors;

   public ErrorResources(List<MyError> err){
      this.total=err.size();
      errors.put("errors", err); 
   }
}
```

I found some related issues on github of Spring Hateoas project.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/279

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/324

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/288

I tried one of the suggestions of the issues above, when added `@JsonSerialze(using=Jackson2HalModule.HalLinkListSerializer)` on **links** of MyError class.

Got message similar with **can not find the correct HttpMessageConverter**, the content type of result is `application/ocect`(binary).

I also tried set the default contentType or default viewResolver to MappingJackson2JsonView, all did not change the result.

Whend I added a custom `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in my config:

```
  @Bean
  @Order(1)
  public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter() {

    ObjectMapper halObjectMapper=ctx.getBean("_halObjectMapper", ObjectMapper.class);

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter =
        new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    jacksonMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(halObjectMapper);
    jacksonMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(
        Arrays.asList(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8, MediaType.ALL));

    return jacksonMessageConverter;
  }
```

The error result is rendered as expected. But I do not think it is the correct way, because I used `MediaType.ALL` here. And it caused another big problem.

I used `TestRestTemplate` to test my rest APIs. The restTemlate tried to treat the input data as XML. I saw in the exception it indicated it tried to invoke a XmlHttpMessageConverter to process the content(it is json), even I have set the accept header as `application/json`. Of course, before I upgraded to Spring Boot 1.3 stack, it worked.

**Stage 2:**

I tried to use `Resources` and `Resource` to wrap the error result.

```
public class ErrorDetails{}//pojo includes error description fields

public class ErrorResource extends Resource<ErrorDetails>{
}

public class ErrorResources extends Resources<ErrorResource>{
}

public class ErrorMessage {
  int total;
  ErrorResources errors;
}
```

Spring still can not render the error result as hal format, it is application/json. When I added 
`@JsonSerialze(using=Jackson2HalModule.HalResourcesSerializer)` on `ErrorResources` class, it raised an exception which complained the `HalResourcesSerializer` does not has a default constructor.

In the @ControllerAdvice class, I have tried to set the method return type to ErrorMessage and a wrapper `ResponseEntity` , it does not work.

Finally, my question is **how to render the response body in a `@ControllerAdvice` same as the one in a normal `@RestController`**? Why it does not work in a `@ControllerAdvice` class?

Is there a simple workaroud for this issue?